# Magento2 - Custom module with tinymce does not show the image source correctly?

Tags: magento2.3, tinymce

I have added tinymce on my magento2 custom module but the image on front end  doesn't show. On inspect element the source of image is like this

```
src="{{media url="wysiwyg/10ux0018sa.jpg"}}"
```

If I use static url it works, but i don't know if that is the best solutions.

Comment: check with this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19737

Comment: @AnasMansuri Still can not fix it.

Comment: what is your magento version?

Comment: Magento/2.3 (Community)